# Why are special characters being jumbled when my HTML form is submitted to a PHP script?

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, special-characters

Basically, I have a form that restaurant owners can fill out that (among other things) asks for the business name.

If something like **"Foobar Café"** is entered, it is stored in the MySQL database as **"Foobar CafÃ©"**. Why is it doing that?

Both the HTML page and database table are set to UTF-8 encoding (the "business_name" field has a collation of "`utf8_unicode_ci`"). Shouldn't that take care of everything? What exactly could be causing the special character `"é" (&etilde;)` to be stored in the database as `"Ã©"`? It makes no sense.

Comment: If you would display the same to the front end user, it would display it perfectly. Do you want them to be stored in the database with exact tildes/acutes for some specific reason?

Comment: Did you try debugging the PHP? Have the AJAX return the POST/GET variable and check what it is in firebug. That will give you a hint as to whether it is happening between the HTML and the PHP, or the PHP and the database.

Comment: On the PHP page that is called by the form "action" attribute, I echo the POSTed content directly, and it shows correctly as "Café". So the problem must be in storing it into the MySQL database. Hope that helps. Also, an email is sent to the site admin(s) when a new business is added, and the name in the email message shows the incorrect characters. That's why I need the correct info in the database. Why wouldn't I anyway?

Comment: Something else that's interesting... I output the business name to a .txt file, and it's incorrect there as well (http://dbfl.xylotdesign.com/vendor/input.txt) ! What's up with that?

Comment: Furthermore (sorry for the multiple comments, but there's a time limit on edits), the email is sent using the POST data, not from database data. So it seems the problem is in the sending of the data. According to Firefox, the page with the form has UTF-8 encoding (http://dbfl.xylotdesign.com/vendor/register.php). I'm stumped.

Comment: Even MORE information: on the PHP action page, `echo $_POST['business_name']` shows **"Café"**, whereas `echo htmlentities($_POST['business_name'])` shows **"CafÃ©"**. This is making less and less sense with every test I perform!

Comment: show your code. Do you use any functions that do not support utf8, or forgot to add the character set to a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing it is from the form not mysql since the email comes from there. Look into that. Maybe you have a ”pre processor” of some sort.

Just wondering, why do you store html chars when you will be displaying that info to users? That's a recipe for disaster. XSS.

A quick fix, try using htmlentites on the data with uft-8 turned on. Send the email as html and you should be fine.

However, try to find the cause of the issue.

***Edit.***
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8");

That should solve your issue.  Charset for utf 8 must be defined

Comment: With your last comment, it makes sense. Add utf-8 as your locale in htmlentities.

Comment: That worked! Thank you very much! I never noticed that `htmlentities()` took an option to specify the character set. Also, what do you suggest I do instead to prevent XSS?

Comment: You are already doing it. I initially thought you weren't using htmlentities. Your last comment made it clear. Glad I helped.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It just seems odd that this needs to be done in order for data to be stored AND displayed properly.

Comment: It's actually the escaping. The storage I and everything is fine. Php just jumbles utf8. But yes, it should auto detect, or even make UTF8 default IMO since UTF8 is now almost ubiquitous. I await php6.

Answer (score 3):

Your database *connection* is probably not set to UTF-8.

At the start of your connection, issue the following query:

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
```

That will set the connection character set to utf8 which will match the encoding and collation of your tables, code and client page.

Comment: This alone didn't fix my problem, but I now have my connect script call this query every time after it establishes the connection and database selection.

Comment: I had the same issue and this single line solved my problem!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings for the respective db table or db, set it to to utf-8